# Permanently ban after N connections in a minute with iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to craft a few iptables rules that will do this:

If a source ip attempts 3 or more connections in under a minute, then ban that ip until further notice.

I'm not very familiar with iptables and this is harder to implement than I thought it would be. Most of the examples I've found only block for 60 seconds. If somebody could show me how to do this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the ipset module might be the most direct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. It does require creating an ipset first, though.

This is what I've come up with and it seems to work:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 -j SET --add-set blocked src

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set blocked src -j DROP
```

Comment: NOTE: If your goal is flood protection then don't reinvent the wheel. You can use existing DDoS protection. Some CDNs will do this for free:
https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/

Answer (score 3):

You could use fail2ban to automatically manage your iptables. It monitors log files and takes action based on criteria that you can configure. It can handle a number of different connection types by default. Using this framework I'm sure you could block any behavior you want.

https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

FROM README:

> Fail2Ban scans log files like [file:///var/log/pwdfail pwdfail] and
>   bans IP addresses that make too many password failures.  It updates
>   firewall rules to reject the IP address.  These rules can be defined
>   by the user.  Fail2Ban can read multiple log files such as sshd or
>   Apache Web server ones. This README is a quick introduction to
>   Fail2Ban.  More documentation, FAQ, HOWTOs are available on the
>   project website.

Answer (score 1):

There's an --hitcount option which specifies the number of failed attempts. 
I suggest you test this on a test computer or something, not SSH-ing to a remote server as you might get locked. Unless you have KVM console access.

A similar answer is given here:
[Automatically deny hacking attempts in CentOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/478341/automatically-deny-hacking-attempts-in-centos)

For more seconds, just specify your value and it should work.

Something to always keep in mind, is that DROP rules must be at the end of the rules.
Usually the iptables rules file is located in /etc/sysconfig/iptables

For other options, you can check https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables. You can find almost anything on the linux.die.net page. It includes the linux man pages and more.

To check the list of banned IPs, you can run: iptables -L INPUT -v -n
Check this for more:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-check-ip-blocked-against-iptables/

And, what I personally found useful is this guide: https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/15473-introduction-to-iptables

Comment: Storing a list of banned ip addresses in iptables will eventually kill your performance.  **ipset** was specifically design to manage large list of IP addresses.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing this @cybernard!